# Magento doesn't pick up my install script

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a new attribute to category management via install script. For some reason, Magento just doesn't use it.

It's a very small module (3 files)

Here's a directory tree in app/code/local:

```
Ageno
-----TopMarki
-------------etc
----------------config.xml
-----Model
----------Mysql4
----------------Setup.php
-----sql
--------topmarki_setup
----------------------mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
```

config.xml:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <topmarki_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ageno_TopMarki</module>
                    <class>Ageno_TopMarki_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>            
            </topmarki_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>

    <modules>
        <Ageno_TopMarki>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Ageno_TopMarki>
    </modules>    
</config>
```

Setup.php:

```
<?php

class Ageno_TopMarki_Model_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup
{
}
```

mysql4-install-0.1.0.php:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'topMarka1', array(
    'input'   => 'image',
    'type'    => 'varchar',
    'group' => 'General',
    'label'         => 'Top Marka 1',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'frontend_input' =>'',
    'backend' => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',   
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible_on_front'  => 1,
));

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
 $entityTypeId,
 $attributeSetId,
 $attributeGroupId,
 'topMarka1',
 '999'  //sort_order
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Despite all that, there is still no new field in "Manage Categories". It should sort of install automatically, am I missing something?

EDIT: adding Ageno_TopMarki.xml to /etc/modules solved the problem. Thank you R.S

Comment: Check `core_resource` table if `topmarki_setup` entry is already there.

Comment: I have disabled caching.

Comment: Take a look at core_resources tables, does topmarki_setup exist?

Comment: Did you add the Ageno_TopMarki.xml to /etc/modules?

Comment: adding Ageno_TopMarki.xml to /etc/modules solved the problem. Thank you R.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add  Ageno_TopMarki.xml to /etc/modules/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ageno_TopMarki>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ageno_TopMarki>
    </modules>
</config>
```